# Django admin 'save_as' with inlines

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

Should 'save_as' work with inlines. I'm rather baffled by the traceback but it doesn't seem to show much involvement of my own code.

The problem seems to be the id's of inlines being set to '' when saving an add form. This is handled quite happily by when you do a normal 'add':

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  307.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  197.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  28.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  24.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in inner
  217.                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  879.                                   prefix=prefix, queryset=inline.queryset(request))
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  682.                                                 queryset=qs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  415.         super(BaseModelFormSet, self).__init__(**defaults)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in __init__
  47.         self._construct_forms()
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in _construct_forms
  108.             self.forms.append(self._construct_form(i))
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  691.         form = super(BaseInlineFormSet, self)._construct_form(i, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _construct_form
  437.                 connection=connections[self.get_queryset().db])
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py" in inner
  53.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py" in inner
  53.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_lookup
  306.             value = self.get_prep_lookup(lookup_type, value)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  292.             return self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/Users/andybaker/.virtualenvs/nmdc_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  479.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/property_manager/property/add/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: it looks like an int field is being left blank. without any more info it is difficult to know which

Comment: To help you solve the problem, clone your project, strip down your models and admin to the absolute minimum that still throws the error and post them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to this if you're using FileFields? https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14760